# Migrate Smiley from mssql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, data-migration, bcp

I have been trying to migrate smiley contained data from ms sql database to mysql database using MySql Workbench. But I'm getting an error like " Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D' for column". I have tried many ways like setting the following parameters.

```
character_set_client = utf8mb4
character_set_connection = utf8mb4
character_set_database = utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem = binary
character_set_results = utf8mb4
character_set_server = utf8mb4
character_set_system = utf8
collation_connection = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
collation_database = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
```

But nothing works.

I have also tried using BCP queryout(BCP for exporting data from SSMS and MySql Import for importing to MySql) and it fails too.

i have used the below query for bcp

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM database.schema.table"  
queryout D:\Data\test.csv -w -U username -P password -S server
```

And used Mysql Table data Import utility

it shows the error " Unhandled exception: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string.".

i have tried changing  Line Separator and  Field Separator but it didn't do any good

Comment: Have you also trieed utf-16?

Comment: @nbk how can we implement utf-16

Comment: try thhis systax for your table  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf16.html  but i think you should try https://www.exasol.com/support/browse/SOL-448 to get proper utf 8

Comment: @nbk My table supports smiley insertion . But it fails while migrating from sql server to mysql .

Comment: Your sql ser ver is in utf 16 or ucs2, as long you don't show any create table from mysql i guess it is utf8. My recoendation is convert all in ms sql to utf8 and import it(shown ion the secnd link) or try yout luck with utf 16 or ucs2 .as shown in link one